# Canceling task currently running in background using PyQGis?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I am trying to close QgsProject on loading layer (if password and username from QgSProject - datasource are  incorrect) before QgsCredentialDialog is shown.

*on signal :*

> QgsProject.instance().loadingLayer.connect(self.load_log)

- If password and user are correct -> pass
- if password and user are not  correct: close the project

*I am using :*

```
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    project.clear()
```

but QgsCredentialDialog still shows up.

[image]

after clear project if I use :

> iface.actionExit().trigger()

This shows up:

[image]

If I click yes, QgsCredentialDialog is shown again

How do I close the project and everything connected with that project (signals,actions,tasks,connections,...)?

**NOTE:**

```
QgsTaskManager().cancelAll() # NOT WORKING
tasks = QgsApplication.taskManager().activeTasks()
for task in tasks:
    print (task.canCancel()) # False
    print (task.description()) # Loading “C:/Users/User/Desktop/some_project.qgs”
    print (task.flags()) # <qgis._core.QgsTask.Flags object at 0x000002330527E4C8>

    task.cancel() # NOT WORKING
```

Since task.canCancel() is FALSE (I think that is main problem here), is it possible to change task.canCancel() into TRUE?

Comment: If the tasks are contained in [QgsTaskManager](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsTaskManager.html), you could try cancelling it using `QgsTaskManager().cancelAll()` before creating a new project.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work either :( If I click yes in dialog "Active Tasks" QgsCredentialDialog is shown again @Joseph

Comment: Duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318585/forcing-qgstask-to-cancel-in-qgis-plugin